# AWK - code not executing sequentially within the END rule

Tags: awk

I'm processing a single file, creating two different associative arrays to count the frequency of two different patterns (i.e. fields 3 and 6, when found).

File sample:

```
2019-06-20 : INFO : XYZ_6789 : [Command [cmd_zip_files]:] Standard output and error
2019-06-20 : INFO : ABC_1234 : License issue
Line with no timestamp
2019-06-20 : INFO : XYZ_6789 : [Command [cmd_zip_files]:] Standard output and error
2019-06-20 : INFO : ABC_1234 : License issue
```

I want to print both arrays at the end, but their outputs overlap.

I'm using GNU Awk 4.1.3.

I've tried to use "next/continue" statements, but they don't seem to be the answer.

Maybe I'm using the END rule in a wrong way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

BEGIN {
  FS="\\)? : \\(?| \\| |[][]"
  MSG_COL=3
  CMD_COL=6
  SEP="=================="
}

{
  if (match ($MSG_COL, /^[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]+/))
      msg_count[$MSG_COL]++

  if ($MSG_COL == "XYZ_6789")
    cmd_count[$CMD_COL]++
}

END {

  print ">> Count of msg <<"

  for (msg in msg_count)
    if (msg_count[msg] > 0)
      print msg_count[msg], msg | "sort -n"

  print ">> Count of cmd <<"

  for (cmd in cmd_count)
    print cmd_count[cmd], cmd | "sort -n"

}
```

I would expect my code to provide the following output:

```
>> Count of msg <<
2 ABC_1234
2 XYZ_6789
>> Count of cmd <<
2 cmd_zip_files
```

Although, I'm getting this:

```
>> Count of msg <<
>> Count of cmd <<
2 ABC_1234
2 cmd_zip_files
2 XYZ_6789
```

Comment: You want to explicitly `close()` each pipe.

Comment: @tripleee - the [GAWK user guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) indicates that _when a file or pipe is opened for output, awk remembers the file name or command
associated with it, and subsequent writes to the same file or command are appended to the previous writes. The file or pipe stays open until awk exits._ If I either remove the ```| sort -n``` command or use your advice (i.e. using ```close("sort -n")```), the output doesn't overlap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you don't close the open filehandles yourself. Awk will close them for you eventually when the script terminates, at which point any pending buffered output will be flushed, but the order in which they are closed is not predictable or dependable.

Change the `END` block to explicitly `close` them in the order you want:

```
END {
  print ">> Count of msg <<"
  c = "sort -n"
  for (msg in msg_count)
    if (msg_count[msg] > 0)
      print msg_count[msg], msg | c
  close(c)

  print ">> Count of cmd <<"
  c = "sort -n"
  for (cmd in cmd_count)
    print cmd_count[cmd], cmd | c
  close(c)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using GNU Awk, you should be able to avoid subshells and external utilities by setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`. Below, I've used `@val_num_desc` which sorts by descending numeric value (not index):

```
awk -F ' : ' '
  /^2019/ {Msg[$3]++; if(split($4, A, "[][]") > 1) Cmd[A[3]]++}
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
    print ">> Count of msg <<"
    for(m in Msg) print Msg[m], m
    print ">> Count of cmd <<"
    for(c in Cmd) print Cmd[c], c
  }
' file
```

```
>> Count of msg <<
2 XYZ_6789
2 ABC_1234
>> Count of cmd <<
2 cmd_zip_files
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this advanced feature of GAWK. Thanks for taking the time to test it and apply some changes to the original implementation. Although, I'm not going to use it to make the code more portable and because its value is "global" (i.e. it affects all array traversal for loops). I also want to be able to sort using different fields (i.e. sort's -k flag).